# Unable to clear cookies using browser.cookies.clear

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

I am unable to clear cookies using watir-webdriver and browser.cookies.clear 
Are there any other alternatives ?

Comment: I had problems with removing cookies in Capybara as well and the following post helped me to resolve my issues: [How to clear cookies in Capybara tests (both Selenium and Rack::Test)](http://makandracards.com/makandra/16117-how-to-clear-cookies-in-capybara-tests-both-selenium-and-rack-test)

Comment: After investigating the issue I figured out that cookies are being cleared using cookies.clear method however the problem I have is I am logging into an external site(facebook) via my test site. so cookies.clear method will only work for my domain and my tests fail because I am unable to clear the cookies on the external webpage. I tried going to external site and clear the cookies after each scenario & got the job done but its really a dirty trick and would make my tests brittle. Any better ideas ?

Comment: Hey It might be browser issue..try to update browser and gems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as far as I know a browser based limitation, due to concerns of security and privacy.

Webdriver is interacting with the browser by javascript, and javascript is not allowed to clear all cookies (think how nasty that could be on a malicious site).  In the non testing env, most JS that is executing came from the server of the site you are accessing.  So the most it is allowed to do is clear the cookies for the 'current domain' e.g. the cookies belonging to the current URL.  So if a web page wants to clear all its own cookies, that is OK, but it is not allowed to clear cookies belonging to other domains.

So if you want all your tests to start with fresh cookies, you will need something in the 'Before' section in env.rb that goes to the root of the site in question, and then clears the cookies

BTW the same limitation applies to setting cookies, if you want to create cookies for a specific site, you need to navigate to that site before trying to create them, or nothing gets created.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but FYI only.

Suppose chrome is the chosen browser, when cucumber is running, from the output of `ps -ef | grep chrome` we'll be able to find the customized user data directory which is something like below.

```
--user-data-dir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.G2DgPo
```

And inside that directory, we'll be able to find the `Cookies` file stored under the `Default` folder.

Not sure directly deleting that database file could fulfill the needs or not. Cause in a normal browser session, such runtime data are stored at

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies
```